# Error 500 when adding contextual filter in a view

Tags: 7, views, datetime

I am working on a site for a radio.
I need to show the programmes in a schedule table.
People in the radio [used to do it](http://www.radio-occitania.com/programas.php) with an Excell document saved in html, I displayed in an iframe. Now I want the Calendar module to generate it, so it's possible to edit the [schedule on the Drupal site](http://remy-web.com/radio/fr/calendar-node-field-date/week/2018-W15).

I created a node type for the various programmes, it has a date field to indicated the time it is broacasted (with repeat). 
Some programmes are aired more than twice. My content type has a second and third date field for these informations.

I set the ‘week’ display of the ‘calendar’ view to grab that precise content type. I added a contextual filter to take into account a second broadcasting in the week.
It works (though some programmes do not show up on Sundays).
When I wanted a third date taken into account I got an Ajax alert about a Error 500.

[image: capture vue]
I get an error when I choose [Contenu: RE-rediff - date de début(field_rediff3)], though it is shown as available.

```
/* Filtre contextuel: Date : Date (node) */
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['date_argument']['id'] = 'date_argument';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['date_argument']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['date_argument']['field'] = 'date_argument';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['date_argument']['default_action'] = 'default';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['date_argument']['exception']['title'] = 'Tout';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['date_argument']['default_argument_type'] = 'date';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['date_argument']['granularity'] = 'week';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['date_argument']['granularity_reset'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['date_argument']['add_delta'] = 'yes';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['date_argument']['date_fields'] = array(
  'field_data_field_date.field_date_value' => 'field_data_field_date.field_date_value',
  'field_data_field_rediff.field_rediff_value' => 'field_data_field_rediff.field_rediff_value',
);
```

Comment: can you share your contextual filter configuration

Comment: Do you mean what I can read when exporting?

Comment: can you add the full Ajax error message you get? and are there any watchdog errors logged when this happens?

Comment: I reported all I had here https://www.drupal.org/project/views/issues/2351135#comment-12559206